# java ChatServer with GUI

Tags: java, swing, chat

I am trying to implement a chatserver with using GUI components. I implemented 3 parts(Server,Client and GUI components).

Following are a few problems I have -

- I can't wrap the code with GUI code.
- When talking with clients, it only works when everybody enter only one line and press enter.

Code:

**First GUI component:**

```
public class ChatServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String str;

    public ChatServer() {
        initComponents();      
        screen.setEditable(false);
    }

private void sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    str = enter.getText();
    enter.setText("");
    screen.append(str+"\n");

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ChatServer().setVisible(true);
}

    private javax.swing.JTextPane enter;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea screen;
    private javax.swing.JButton send;

}
```

and it looks like:

[image]

**This my server code:**

```
public class Server {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(23);
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost()+" hazir");
        while(true){
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println(s.getInetAddress().getHostName() + " baglandi");
            new ServerPart(s).start();
        }
    }

}

public class ServerPart extends Thread {
    private Socket s;
    public ServerPart(Socket s){
        this.s=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

            ps.println("Hello" + s.getInetAddress().getHostName());

            String gelen;

            while(true){ 

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());   

            gelen = sc.nextLine();

            if(gelen.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
                break;


            System.out.println("Client: " + gelen);

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( 
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

            ps.println("Server: " + input.readLine());

            }

            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**Client code:**

```
public class Client extends Thread {
    private Socket s;
    public Client(Socket s){
        this.s=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

            ps.println("Hello" + s.getInetAddress().getHostName());

            String gelen;

            while(true){

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( 
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

            gelen = sc.nextLine();

            if(gelen.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
                break;

            System.out.println("Client: " + gelen);
            ps.println("Server: " + input.readLine());


            }

            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws UnknownHostException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.173", 23);

        new Client(s);

    }

}
```

Would appreciate if you can help me mates.

Comment: You don't "wrap" one code in the GUI code. You first create true OOPs classes that act as your non-GUI model and then use the model in the GUI. If you don't know how to create OOP classes with non-static fields and methods, check out the tutorials. You will definitely want to also check out the tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) before attempting to create this.

Comment: More info in [homework - java chat application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582097/java-chat-application) thread here in SO. As @Hovercraft mentions, you need to work on your basics. Try to understand the examples mentioned in the SO post above.

Comment: well ok i will go on search these topics. thank guys.

Comment: well you can be sure that it is not a homework ;) it just a work that which a student wanna develope himself on java ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are  using `PrintStream` class , with method `ps.readline();`.  If you are developing a chat application, then this approach will not work, as readline method terminate the stream when found newline or End of file, or when carriage return i.e. enter.  So I do prefer to use.. datainputstream  and dataoutputstream --

```
Socket sc = new Socket("address",port);
DataOutputStream daos;
DataInputStream dis;
dis = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
daos= new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: 1) `PrintStream` has no `readLine()` *or* `readLine()` method.  2) There are no class by the name `datainputstream` *or* `dataoutputstream` in the J2SE.  3) Please spell like an adult (I.E. spelling *all 3* letters of the word 'are'). 4) The code button is there to cause code to be formatted.  Just select the code and click the `{}` button above the message posting form.